# Jquery script not showing in firebug or firing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, firebug

I'm trying to get a drop down box to alter a second drop down box through the use of a jquery/ajax script. Firebug is showing Jquery is working but my script isn't showing  at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxfunction(parent)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../functions/process.php?parent=' + parent;
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#sub").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

process.php is just a MySQL query (which works)

My initial drop down box is populated by a MySQL query

```
<select name="front-size" onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
//Query
</select>
```

And then the second drop down box is just

```
<select name = "front-finish" id="sub">
</select>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you see your ajax call in Firebug ? Do you have any error in the console ?

Comment: Ah I do now.ReferenceError: ajaxfunction is not defined

Comment: Look into my ans it will work for you

Comment: I think you have an issue with jQuery inclusion. When it's ok, the ajax call will be visible and it should be ok. Advice: avoid inline code like `onchange=...`. Prefer adding javascript behaviour with the `.ready()` method of jQuery and `.on('change', callback)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling inline function is not good at all... as web 2.0 standards suggest using unobtrusive JS rather than onevent attributes....check out why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)..
other thigs..correct way to use ajax is by using  type and data ajax option to send values in controller..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('select[name="front-size"').change(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../functions/process.php',
            type:'get',
            data:{'value' : $(this).val()}, 
            dataType:"html",   //<--- here this will take the response as html... 
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sub").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

and your proces.php should be..

```
 <?php
   //db query ...thn get the value u wanted.. 
   //loop through it..
   $optVal .= "<option value="someDbValue">some DDB values</option>";
   // end loop

   echo $optValue;exit;
```

**updated**

looks like you still have `onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)"` this in your select remove that it is not needed and the ajaxfunction in javascript too...

```
<select name="front-size" >    
                   //----^ here remove that
```

Comment: It should be like $optVal. = "<option value.." like that else it will return only the last row in DB

Comment: Hmm I continue to get a 'ajaxfunction undefined' error in firebug

Comment: look like you ar still calling the inline funtion.. remove that ..check my updates

Answer (score 0):

In your process.php give like this

```
echo "<select name='front-finish' id='sub' onchange='ajaxfunction(this.value)'>";
```

like this you need to add the "onchange" function to the newly created select box through ajax

or you can remove onchange function and write like

```
$("select[name^='front-']").live('change',function(){
   //Do your ajax call here
});
```

Comment: Iam giving 2 soultions and the second one will work better if he has 2 or more select boxes and also he is updating entire select box through ajax....thats why instead of adding onchange event on every ajax call I suggetsed to add event....I think it should better

Answer (score 0):

use `jQuery.on()` that will allow us to add events on dynamically loaded content.

```
$('select[name^="front-"]').on('change',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).val();
    ajaxfunction(value);
});
```

`[name^="front-"]` this will select all the `SELECT` box having `name` starts with `front-`.